# Python tkinter class 2 buttons, only 1 visible

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I wrote a class in python tkinter that you can use to create buttons that change their images on leave, enter and button-1 event.

The script:

```
from tkinter import *

class ImageButton:

    def CreateButton(self, image, root):
        # --- image setup ---
        self.ImageName = image
        self.ButtonRoot = root
        self.normal = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.ImageName + "/normal.png")
        self.hover = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.ImageName + "/hover.png")
        self.clicked = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.ImageName + "/clicked.png")
        # --- button setup ---
        self.Button = Button(self.ButtonRoot, image=self.normal)
        self.Button.bind("<Leave>", self.normal_event)
        self.Button.bind("<Enter>", self.hover_event)
        self.Button.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_event)
        return self.Button

    def normal_event(self, event):
        self.Button.config(image=self.normal)

    def hover_event(self, event):
        self.Button.config(image=self.hover)

    def click_event(self, event):
        self.Button.config(image=self.clicked)


Root = Tk()
Image = ImageButton()


FirstButton = Image.CreateButton("scann_device", Root)
FirstButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

SecondButton = Image.CreateButton("get_device_info", Root)
SecondButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

Root.mainloop()
```

So if you create a button with that class, you can do anything you want. It only binds it to the events I mentioned above. If you create 1 button, it works and you see it on your window, but if you create 2 buttons and grid/pack them, it wont work. It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1YJV.png). The second button also gets the hitbox of the first button.

Comment: You are using classes in a very strange way - you're only creating a single instance of your class, so there's exactly one `self.Button` and other such attributes.  In other words, each button is overwriting all of the previous one's details.  You need a new instance of the class for each button; renaming `CreateButton` to `__init__` so that it is automatically invoked on instance creation would be the first step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only initiate one instance of `Image`. Therefore, in your second call to `CreateButton()`, all class objects (`self.normal`, `self.ImageName`, `self.Button`) are overwritten with the new values.

You are probably better off inheriting a class from the tkinter Button and adding your own functions. See this example:

```
from tkinter import *

class ImageButton(Button):

    def __init__(self, image, root, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(root, *args, **kwargs)
        # --- image setup ---
        self.image_name = image
        self.normal = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.image_name + "/normal.png")
        self.hover = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.image_name + "/hover.png")
        self.clicked = PhotoImage(file="Images/" + self.image_name + "/clicked.png")
        # --- button setup ---
        self.config(image=self.normal)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.normal_event)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.hover_event)
        self.bind("<Button-1>", self.click_event)

    def normal_event(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.normal)

    def hover_event(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.hover)

    def click_event(self, event):
        self.config(image=self.clicked)


root = Tk()

FirstButton = ImageButton("scann_device", root)
FirstButton.grid(row=0, column=0)

SecondButton = ImageButton("get_device_info", root)
SecondButton.grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```